# Phonegap cordova.js on pc

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm developing app with `PhoneGap`.

Most of the things I test on pc in normal `browser` rather than on my `device`.

But now I need to test things that uses `cordova.js` stuff that is not included in www directory. There is different `cordova.js` file for each `platform` so I'm not sure what to include to `www` `index.html` file so I can test in on pc?

Is it possible and am I doing it right?

I'm aware that cordova.js is included during building process, but I've found testing on pc useful and thats why I would like to include it (for development time at least)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if you add a cordova.js it will be useless without the native code it calls.

I don't think it makes any sence trying to test native functionnalities in your pc. You should really test either on real devices or in emulators.

You could have a look at ripple to be able to test cordova functions in chrome : http://emulate.phonegap.com/

But again, it will not replace testings in real devices (cordova tends to have different behaviours with each version of android for example)

Answer (score 1):

You always want to make any changes in the base `www` folder. There should be a `platforms folder`, `plugin folder` and `www folder` in the root of the project. The reason you want to modify that `www folder` in the root of the project is because anytime you rebuild the application is clears out everything in the `platforms folder`

So for an example I have a `platforms/ios` and a `platforms/android` that contains a www folder inside of those as well but each time I run `phonegap build android` or `phonegap build ios` it recreates every file within those directories

So you'd want to make code changes in the root `www` folder and copy over the changes to the `platforms/android/assets/www` folder or `platforms/ios/www` then navigate to that directory in the browser

Comment: However, OP wants to point his or her browser to the HTML files for testing. This means OP should navigate the browser to `/platforms/android/assets/www/` to view changes, but make code changes to `/www/`, then rebuild the project to view the changes....kind of a pain.